# Why are the react-jss style functions not executing on mobx store update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, jss

I am using mobx-react, in conjunction with react-jss library for styling.

The issue that I am facing is that **the store updates are not causing the functions in the style definition to execute with the new props**
The exact scenario can be replicated here 
https://codesandbox.io/s/2wkw6m75kj

Observations -

- I am injecting the styles first using the *injectSheet* method of *react-jss*, followed by the mobx store injection. In this manner the store is available as props to the style rules ( which is needed to update the style dynamically on prop updates), on store updates the components are being re-rendered but the style functions are not executing.
- I have tried using both the injecting functions of mobx and react-jss as decorators instead of as functions, it causes the same behavior.

Mobx version used - 3.5.1
Mobx-react version used - 4.4.2
React-jss version used - 8.4.0
Browser - Electron 1.8.2

I would like to know that if there's something at my end that I can do to work around this issue, or if am doing something wrong here itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `const style` to state, it should pass through condition everytime when page realo

Comment: I don't think that I can move it to being a state component, since I need to refer to the  _styles_ variable for passing it to the **injectSheet** method while creating the _StyledComp_ component itself. 
Also, on page reload. i.e., on initialization it's working expectedly, only on store updates it's not.